# Soap XMl Parsing in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am getting a XML like this

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:authenticateResponse xmlns:ns2="http://auth.mobility.kra.kuali.polus.com/"     xmlns:ns3="http://rice.kuali.org/kim/v2_0">
<Principal>
<ns3:principalId>10000000049</ns3:principalId>
<ns3:principalName>shields</ns3:principalName>
<ns3:entityId>10048</ns3:entityId>
<ns3:active>true</ns3:active>
<ns3:versionNumber>1</ns3:versionNumber>
<ns3:objectId>F07352DB67502CF0E040007F0100035A</ns3:objectId>
</Principal>
</ns2:authenticateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How to parse this kind of xml in android.

I had tried like this  but not working

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("soap:Body");

    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
    {

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use ksoap library for this kind of purpose?  https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlstring.getBytes("UTF-8"));
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(stream);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Principal");

for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

    Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
    NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("ns3:principalId");
    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

    System.out.println("ns3:principalId : "+(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue()));
}
```